# Selenium Webdriver: spawning Javascript Calendar window

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver

In testing a simple website, I find that when using the Firefox webdriver I am unable to get a Javascript calendar window to appear when the button is clicked. I am able to spawn the window in the Selenium IDE but when I run the Java code, the click is registered, but no window is spawned.

The Code I am using to click the Javascript element is:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"Pick a date\"]"));
element.click();
```

Additional info: The 'cal.gif' image is also not shown when using the webdriver. The problem is NOT switching to the calendar window or selecting and element within, it is simply getting the window to spawn at all.

This is the website under test: [Parking Meter](http://adam.goucher.ca/parkcalc/index.php)

I have searched quite a bit for the solution, either I am not searcher the right keywords or I am missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

edit: HTML code for the JS calendar:

```
<a href="javascript:NewCal('EntryDate','mmddyyyy',false,24)"
   <img height="16" width="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date" src="cal.gif"></img>
</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm in mobile. Can you post the html code for the calendar widget?

Comment: just added it in an edit!

Comment: Answered your question.

Comment: Is there a requirement for you to click on the calendar or is it ok if you just enter a valid date.?

Comment: It is required in the test suite that I used the popup calendar

Answer (score 1):

What your doing here is wrong. You need to click on the `a` tag not on the `img` tag.

Look at the below code, which is working fine for me:

```
@Test
public void testSO() throws Exception
{
    driver.get("http://adam.goucher.ca/parkcalc/index.php");

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0).click();
}
```

Change the index to `0` or `1` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I changed my code to match yours and am still not getting any results. This leads me to believe that the problem may be with my Selenium RC, Webdriver, or something to do with my Eclipse. Can you think of any reason that the pop-up wouldn't spawn even though the link is being clicked? The only hint I noticed is that the 'cal.gif' does not properly load with the page is loaded in the Webdriver. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm interesting, what is the browser your trying and selenium version?

Comment: Selenium Server 2.43.1 and the latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Id be using the JavascriptExecutor.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js.executeScript("<JavaScript.click;");
```